# unreachable code detected

Tags: c#

I am getting unreachable code detected for the second if statement. Can you please let me know what went wrong?

```
private bool ValidateSettings()
{
    if (chkDownload.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAppName.Text))
    {
        divAppDownloadError.Visible=true;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (chkpplaORfmp.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfmpORppla.Text))
    {
        divXPAAPPDownloadError.Visible = true;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
         return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private bool ValidateSettings()
{
    if (chkDownload.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAppName.Text) && chkpplaORfmp.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfmpORppla.Text))
    {
        divAppDownloadError.Visible = true;
        divXPAAPPDownloadError.Visible = true;
        return false;
    }
    if ((chkDownload.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAppName.Text)) || (chkpplaORfmp.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfmpORppla.Text)))
    {
        if (chkDownload.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAppName.Text))
        {
            divAppDownloadError.Visible = true;
            divXPAAPPDownloadError.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            divXPAAPPDownloadError.Visible = true;
            divAppDownloadError.Visible = false;
        }
        return false;
    } return true; 

}
```

this is working

Comment: But much messier than it needs to be.

Answer (score 26):

This is because the first `if/else` block will return either way - no code after that block will execute:

```
if(chkDownload.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAppName.Text))
{
    // You either return here
    divAppDownloadError.Visible=true;
    return false;
}
else
{
    // or here - after this statement how can anything
    // else possible execute?
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want to **remove the `else` blocks and just return `true` at the end.**

Looks like you want to return `false` if any of the settings are not as expected. Let:

condition1 = `chkDownload.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAppName.Text)`
condition2 = `chkpplaORfmp.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfmpORppla.Text)`

The way it is written, we have

- (condition1, condition2) = (true, true) => return true
- *(condition1, condition2) = (true, false) => return true*
- (condition1, condition2) = (false, true) => return false
- (condition1, condition2) = (false, false) => return false

What it looks like you want is:

- (condition1, condition2) = (true, true) => return true
- *(condition1, condition2) = (true, false) => return false*
- (condition1, condition2) = (false, true) => return false
- (condition1, condition2) = (false, false) => return false

Answer (score 1):

Your code is the equivalent of this, since both the `if` and `else` contain return statements:

```
private bool ValidateSettings()
{
    if(chkDownload.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAppName.Text))
    {
        divAppDownloadError.Visible=true;
        return false; 
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Samuel Carrijo is right; I think what you mean to do is check if any invalidating conditions are held and, if so, return `false`. But to check them all you must not return `true` until the end:

```
private bool ValidateSettings()
{
    if (chkDownload.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAppName.Text))
    {
        divAppDownloadError.Visible=true;
        return false;
    }

    if (chkpplaORfmp.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfmpORppla.Text))
    {
        divXPAAPPDownloadError.Visible = true;
        return false;
    }

    // if you've gotten this far, neither of the
    // invalidating conditions above were held;
    // so you're good!
    return true;
}
```

Comment: if i return boolean value after checking condition1 then condition 2 is not checked but i want to evaluate for both condition 1 and condition2
i.e the following condition is not satisfied
((condition1, condition2) = (false, false) => return false

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool ValidateSettings()
{
  if ((chkDownload.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAppName.Text))||
    (chkpplaORfmp.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfmpORppla.Text)))
  {
    if (chkDownload.Checked)
    divAppDownloadError.Visible=true;
    else divXPAAPPDownloadError.Visible = true;

    return false;
  }

    return true;
  }
```

Code simplified

Comment: ok hit me up with a vote up or a selected answer if it works for you